# Is it possible to create a NN with an input layer that is bigger when training and smaller when running?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I would be interested to try and train a neural network with the following data. (X coordinate, Y coordinate, Z coordinate and distance)*4 and have an output of X, Y coordinate. My ideea is that at runtime feesing the XYZ+distance is not useful as only the distance changes and XYZ always stay the same. Is it possible to train with XYZ+ distance and run with only distance?

I have tried Tensor flow with the full NN but now I would like to reduce the size as I want it to be running in an embedded context.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **sequential model starting with a dense layer** W (most frequent case) you can skip a part of the first matrix:

*(X Y Z d) · W*

*= (X Y Z d) · (C1 | C2 | ... )*

*= ((X Y Z) · C1_[1:3] | (X Y Z) · C2_[1:3] | ...) + (d · C1_[4] | d · C2_[4] | ...)*

Here the first vector is actually constant and can be computed once and for all.
Then compute the second vector and the rest of your model (don't forget the 1st activation!). Unfortunately in this case you cannot reduce more the size of the architecture as all inputs of the layers change starting from the 1st activation when *d* change

To improve the efficiency of this tip you can try to use parallel branches at the beginning to merge after instead of a sequential model